# MS Access unbound textbox in tabular form - Student attendance

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

I am creating a DBMS for a school and in implementing student attendance, I have encountered an issue. I have a query that pulls the names of the students enrolled into classes and created a subform to contain that information. This subform has two additional fields (unbound text box and a combo box) that users will enter information to which will be updated into the attendance table using an append query.

It is with these unbound text boxes I am having problems. 
Basically, when data is entered into these text boxes it updates for every record instead of just the single record.

[image]

As you can see from the picture above, adding late and 10 mins in the first line adds the same value to all records.

More screenshots below, please let me know if any additional information is required.

[image]

Comment: That's normal behavior. If you want each row to have a different value, you should bound the control to a field in your data source.

Comment: Show us your underlying queries